# Edited Question "Books and information regarding CAPM" into Shape!

Tags: discussion, editing

I just found this post [Books and information regarding CAPM [Original Revision]](https://pm.stackexchange.com/revisions/2528/1), which at first glance didn't seem very constructive:

> What are the best books or study material for the CAPM certification?
>
> I have seen that many websites claim that they have brain dumps for CAPM like they said they have for CISCO, Java and Microsoft. I am **strickly** saying that I am not going to use those dumps and nor I recommend anyone to use that because they do nothing but decrease your knowledge. But I am curoius to know that does CAPM has a definateset of questions for the exam like CISCO, Java and Microsoft ?

The op was asking for a list of books, which is a poor question for the Stack Exchange model. However, [Trevor Nelson](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/921/trevor-k-nelson) did such a great job answering the question that I was able to edit the question and tailor it to the answer.

The [revised question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/books-and-information-regarding-capm) now reads:

> I have seen that many websites claim that they have brain dumps for CAPM like they said they have for CISCO, Java and Microsoft. I am **strictly** saying that I am not going to use those dumps and nor I recommend anyone to use that because they do nothing but decrease your knowledge. But I am curious to know this:
>
> Will the study material for the CAPM certification be different than the study material for the PMP? What is the difference?
>
> Does CAPM have a definite set of questions for the exam like CISCO, Java and Microsoft?

I'm hoping this helps serve as another example of how an older question could be edited into shape. If this inspires you or helps you see how other [recently closed questions](https://pm.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a1) could be given a second chance, feel free to try your hand at an edit.

Closed questions are editable solely for the purpose of giving the op, and the community, an opportunity to fix them and turn them into a valuable resource.

Comment: Thanks for this example!  :)